# Reverse path forwarding using POX controller

Tags: sdn, pox

I want to ping a host from my POX control program and check for response. I want to do this to test if the host really exists. How will I ping a host from the control program?

Comment: I have created the control program that monitors the traffic. Could nott find any way to send a ping packet from the CP to the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick solution is to make a ping using the python language and the os capabilities.Assuming you started the mininet emulator with

```
sudo mn --controller=remote
```

First give the switch an ip in order for the ping to find a route to go to the host. Open a new terminal to ssh to your mininet vm

```
ssh -X mininet@192.168.56.101
```

change 192.168.56.101 if your mininet vm has a different ip. In this new terminal type

```
ifconfig s1
```

you should get something like

> ```
>         Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:64:44:9a:f9:4f  
>         UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>         RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>         TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>         collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
> ```

which indicates that your switch does not have an ip. To give an ip to the switch we have to

```
sudo ifconfig s1 10.0.1.1
```

and then ping a host connected to this switch (ie. 10.0.0.1) from your POX program.

```
import os
host_ip = "10.0.0.1" #the host ip you want to ping from controller
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + host_ip)

#check the response...
if response == 0:
    print host_ip, 'is up!'
else:
    print host_ip, 'is down!'
```

Comment: the switch has an ip by default in mininet and this is not working.

Comment: do you know how to get the ips of the hosts through POX or the terminal?

Comment: yes <name> ifconfig , is this what you are talking about?

Comment: in my case if I run `sudo mn --controller=remote` and then `ifconfig s1` it gives me `s1        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a6:30:52:8f:d3:4f  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1` which is perfectly normal since I have not instructed anywhere for the switch to get an ip. I wonder how your switch has an ip.

Comment: This works but if i run a standalone program from xterm c0 then from there. bu if I add the code to the control program then it does not work

Comment: You should ping from any where inside the mininet vm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114087/discussion-between-sotiristsartsaris-and-alex-ban).